# how to make this menu, toggle then hamburger, then toggle, to a certain size screen

Tags: html, css, menu, navbar, toggle

I have this menu, not made by me, with Bootstrap and Visual Studio. It's not responsive, so I'm doing everything to make it responsive, I'd like it to become toggle at a certain resolution so it's done as a hamburger symbol, any ideas?

```
<ul class="f-cb">
    <li runat="server" id="Li1" visible="true" class="about-li">
        <a class="tit" href="/events_list.aspx" >Eventi</a>
    </li>
    <li runat="server" id="Distributori" visible="false" class="about-li">
        <a class="tit">Area Riservata</a> <%-- Area Riservata Distributori --%>
        <div class="con f-cb none">
            <div class="left">

                <a class="link-b ico_2" href="/DahuaTechDay" runat="server" id="menu_dsd"><i>Dahua HighTech Day</i></a>                    
                <a class="link-b ico_4" href="/AreaRiservata/DSD.aspx" runat="server" id="menu_dsdRecap" visible="false"><i>Dahua HighTech Day Summary</i></a>
                <a class="link-b ico_5" href="/AreaRiservata/test_home.aspx" runat="server" id="menu_Test" visible="false">Formazione e Test</a>
                <a class="link-b ico_5" href="/AreaRiservata/fatturatorebate.aspx" runat="server" id="menu_StatoRebateDist" visible="false">Fatturati e Rebate</a>
                <a class="link-b ico_5" href="/AreaRiservata/AccountWebAuth.aspx" runat="server" id="menu_AccountWebAuth" visible="false">Autorizzazioni Account WEB</a>                    
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li runat="server" id="UtilityLi" visible="false" class="about-li">
        <a class="tit">Utilities</a>
        <div class="con f-cb none">
            <div class="left"> 
                <a class="link-b ico_1" href="/Utilities/CheckDSD.aspx" runat="server"><span><i>- Riepilogo HighTech Day (vecchia gestione) -</i></span></a>                    
                <a class="link-b ico_1" href="/events_management.aspx" runat="server"><span>Riepilogo EVENTI (nuova gestione)</span></a>                    
                <a class="link-b ico_6" href="/Utilities/Accounting/CheckSeriale.aspx"><span>Check SERIAL NUMBER</span></a>                    
                <a class="link-b ico_1" href="/Utilities/Marketing/Form_Chiamate.aspx"><span>Form Chiamate PRIMO CONTATTO</span></a>                    
                <a class="link-b ico_1" href="/Utilities/Marketing/Riepilogo_Form_Chiamate.aspx"><span>Riepilogo Chiamate PRIMO CONTATTO</span></a>                    
                <a class="link-b ico_1" href="/print_certificates.aspx"><span>Stampa Attestati</span></a>       
                <a class="link-b ico_1" href="/cartello_area_videosorvegliata_lista.aspx"><span>Cartelli AREA VIDEOSORVEGLIATA (lista)</span></a>       
                <a class="link-b ico_1" href="/Utilities/TestFormazione_stato.aspx" runat="server" id="menu_FormazioneTest" visible="false"><span>Gestione Formazione e TEST</span></a>                    
                <a class="link-b ico_1" href="/Utilities/AccountWebVideotrend.aspx" runat="server" id="menu_AccountWebVDT" visible="false"><span>Gestione Account WEB (SQL Videotrend)</span></a>     
                <a class="link-b ico_1" href="/RegisterAdmin.aspx" runat="server" id="menu_AccountWebDS" visible="false"><span><i>- Gestione Account WEB (SQL Dahuaservice) -</i></span></a>     
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li runat="server" id="LiAreaRiservata" visible="false" class="about-li">
        <a class="tit" style="color:red;">Area Riservata (2)</a> 
        <div class="con f-cb none">
            <div class="left">
                <a class="link-b ico_2" style="margin-bottom:0px" href="/events_list.aspx" runat="server" id="AreaRiservata_EventiRegistrazione">EVENTI: registrazione</a>                    
                <a class="link-b ico_4" href="/events_management.aspx" runat="server" id="AreaRiservata_EventiGestione" visible="false">EVENTI: gestione</a>                    

                <a class="link-b ico_4" style="margin-bottom:0px" href="/prices_warehouse.aspx" runat="server" id="AreaRiservata_PrezziDisponibilita" visible="false">Prezzi e Magazzino</a>
                <a class="link-b ico_4" style="margin-bottom:0px" href="/shipping_docs.aspx" runat="server" id="AreaRiservata_DocumentiTrasporto" visible="false">Documenti di trasporto</a>
                <a class="link-b ico_4" style="margin-bottom:0px" href="/AreaRiservata/fatturatorebate.aspx" runat="server" id="AreaRiservata_FatturatiRebate" visible="false">Fatturati e rebate</a>
                <a class="link-b ico_4" href="/check_serialnumber.aspx" runat="server" id="AreaRiservata_ControlloSerialNumber" visible="false">Controllo SERIAL NUMBER</a>

                <a class="link-b ico_2" style="margin-bottom:0px" href="/AreaRiservata/test_home.aspx" runat="server" id="AreaRiservata_FormazioneTest">Formazione e TEST</a>                    
                <a class="link-b ico_4" href="/Utilities/TestFormazione_stato.aspx" runat="server" id="AreaRiservata_FormazioneTestGestione" visible="false">Formazione e TEST: gestione</a>
                
                <a class="link-b ico_2" style="margin-bottom:0px" href="/Utilities/Marketing/Form_Chiamate.aspx" runat="server" id="AreaRiservata_PrimoContattoForm">PRIMO CONTATTO: form</a>                    
                <a class="link-b ico_2" href="/Utilities/Marketing/Riepilogo_Form_Chiamate.aspx" runat="server" id="AreaRiservata_PrimoContattoRiepilogo">PRIMO CONTATTO: riepilogo</a>                    

                <a class="link-b ico_2" style="margin-bottom:0px" href="/print_certificates.aspx" runat="server" id="AreaRiservata_StampaAttestati">Stampa ATTESTATI</a>                    
                <a class="link-b ico_2" href="/Utilities/AccountWebVideotrend.aspx" runat="server" id="AreaRiservata_AccountWebGestione">ACCOUNT WEB: gestione</a>       
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So far with the CSS and some media queries, I have reduced the size of the files and I have deleted the part of the bar with the mail but I would like to do it toggle.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1453px) {     header .nav-box a.tit {         transition: color 0.3s;         width: 100%;         height: 100%;         color: rgb(51, 51, 51);         font-size: 13px;         display: block;     } } @media screen and (max-width: 1184px) {     #LabelMember {         display:none;     } }
```